Suggestions for creating a pixel art editing component for my app using using React Native
I'm a beginner in React Native and I have created a pixel art editor component for my application, but it is not as fast as I would like.
The problem is that when the user drags their finger across the screen in a fast motion, the pixels are not being colored in time. Sometimes this also produces "Maximum update depth exceeded" error.
Are there any improvements that can be made in my code or should I use other libraries?
This is the code for my current component:
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useTouchHandler } from '@shopify/react-native-skia';
import { RoundedItem } from './RoundedItem';
import { useAppSelector } from '../state/store';

const DrawingPadGrid = ({ rows, columns, pixelColors, setPixelColors }) => {
    const {width: portraitWidth, height: portraitHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
    const SCREEN_WIDTH = Math.max(portraitWidth, portraitHeight);
    const N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL = columns;
    const N_PIXEL_VERTICAL = rows;
    const SAFE_AREA_PADDING_VERT = 120;
    const CONTAINER_SIZE = (SCREEN_WIDTH-SAFE_AREA_PADDING_VERT) / N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL;
    const PADDING = 3;
    const SQUARE_SIZE = CONTAINER_SIZE - PADDING;
    const CANVAS_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH - SAFE_AREA_PADDING_VERT;
    const CANVAS_HEIGHT = N_PIXEL_VERTICAL * CONTAINER_SIZE;

    const brushColor = useAppSelector(state => state.matrix.color);
    const brushColorRef = useRef(brushColor);
    brushColorRef.current = brushColor;
    let lastPixel = null;

    const drawPixel = useCallback((event) => {
        const i = Math.floor(event.x / CONTAINER_SIZE);
        const j = Math.floor(event.y / CONTAINER_SIZE);
        const pixelKey = `${i + j * N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL}`;
        if(i >= 0 && i < N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL && j >= 0 && j < N_PIXEL_VERTICAL && lastPixel != pixelKey) {
            setPixelColors(prevPixelColors => {
                return { 
                    ...prevPixelColors,
                    [pixelKey]: brushColorRef.current
                };
            });
            lastPixel = pixelKey;
        }
    }, []);

    const touchHandler = useTouchHandler({
        onStart: drawPixel,
        onActive: drawPixel,
        onEnd: () => {
            lastPixel = null;
        },
    });

    return ( 
        <Canvas
            style={{
                width: CANVAS_WIDTH,
                height: CANVAS_HEIGHT,
            }}
            onTouch={ touchHandler }
        >
            {new Array(N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
                return new Array(N_PIXEL_VERTICAL).fill(0).map((_, j) => {
                    return (
                        <RoundedItem
                            key={`i${i}-j${j}`}
                            x={i * CONTAINER_SIZE + PADDING / 2}
                            y={j * CONTAINER_SIZE + PADDING / 2}
                            width={SQUARE_SIZE}
                            height={SQUARE_SIZE}
                            color={pixelColors[`${i + j * N_PIXEL_HORIZONTAL}`]}
                        />
                    );
                });
            })}
        </Canvas>
    );
};

export default DrawingPadGrid;

The RoundedItem is just a memoized RoundedRect with some props.
